# How to set default value of ZIP/Postal code in checkout page - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento-2.1

- In Magento **Checkout Cart page** under **Estimate Shipping and Tax**, we can see text field **ZIP/POSTAL CODE**.
- Already we store ZIP/postal code in checkout session.
- My question is I want to display **ZIP/postal code** text field from checkout session.

Please help me to find solution.

Comment: Madhawan how did you complete this task?